# Added a style file to ~/Library/texmf/tex/latex/circuitikzgit but I still get ! LaTeX Error: File `circuitikzgit.sty' not found

Tags: errors, circuitikz

I'm using a Mac, I created the directory `~/Library/texmf/tex/latex/circuitikzgit` and added the sty file `circuitikzgit.sty` to it. I then ran `sudo texhash ~/Library/texmf`, restarted TeX Live, and my tex editor (texmaker) and still got the error message

`` ! LaTeX Error: File `circuitikzgit.sty' not found. ``

I can't seem to find a solution for this, please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: You shouldn't run `texhash` on the local `texmf`. So navigate to the directory and remove the `ls-R` file (probably need to use `sudo` to remove it).  What does `kpsewhich circuitikzgit.sty` return?  And are you spelling it correctly?

Comment: @KJO The `git` version is the latest development version.  So you need to install it in the local `texmf`.

Comment: @AlanMunn just noticed that (confusing that mentioned  on ctan within the core description) so will delete comment

Comment: @AlanMunn ```kpsewhich circuitikzgit.sty ``` returns nothing.

Comment: @AlanMunn I'm glad you are here. I looked through a few of your posts regarding similar situations, and applied many of your instructions, but none of them worked.

Comment: Putting the .sty file in the working directory (where the .tex file is kept) is the easiest way to get it working.

Comment: The install instruction was supposedly updated but is still wooly "you can find the lat­est git-ver­sion as a sin­gle file, **just copy it to your project** or to your lo­cal tex tree." Without any clarity as to if the subfolder definitely needs to be different to the normal one i.e  /circuitikz  however for what its worth I cant find a place in mytexmf for it to be seen either, and I cant verify MiKTeX is working with personal trees as it seems to keep "forgetting"  me setting them ?

Comment: @JohnKormylo Omar is using a Mac, so unlikely to be using MikTeX.

Comment: @nidhin you are right, that would be the easiest solution. I however, do not want to keep on copying this file over and over again, I simply wanted to add it to my local tree, and use it as many times as I needed. I'm using a mac MacTeX or Tex Live is how other packages are managed, and it doesn't seem to offer the addition of a local directory from the GUI.

Comment: Are you sure you use `~/Library`, the Library folder in your HOME folder rather than `/Library`, the Library folder at the root of your HD?

Comment: @HerbSchulz I'm using ~/Library/ in my home directory, not my HD root.

Comment: Please run `kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFHOME` in Terminal.app and let use know what it returns.

Comment: @HerbSchulz here is the result ```/Users/$MYUSERNAME/Library/texmf```

Comment: Ok. How about `ls -a ~/Library/texmf/tex/latex`?

Comment: ```.  ..  .DS_Store circuitikzgit```

Comment: Did you create that `texmf` tree using `sudo`? If so you may not have read permissions for that set of folders.

Comment: Looking over the problem again, it seems that I have misspelled the names of the directory in the ```~/Library/texmf/circuitikzgit```, now it is working as expected.